# unable to pair my 2014 Muse headband to my 2015 macbook pro

Tags: bluetooth

On macOS 10.13.6, when I select to bluetooth pair my Muse 2014 headband, I see this ...

[image]

Notice that the device is showing up but the "connect" button does not appear next to it. I am uncertain what this means.

Comment: Does it work if you double click on the name (Muse-862D)?

Comment: Remove the profile from the Mac and do a factory reset of the headband (consult your owners guide).  Then pair as if new.  Also, try pairing to a different device like a phone or a tablet.

Comment: Go ahead and write up an answer and I'll be sure to upvote!  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution offered by @Allan works.
I simply click on the X that appears beside the device when I hover the pointer over it.

Then when I hold the button in on the headband to put it into search mode, I am able to make a bluetooth connection on the mac.

Be aware, however, that with the 2014 Muse headband the bluetooth connection will disconnect after a few seconds unless you are actively pulling data from the device with a tool like muse-io. This is, apparently, the intended behavior.

It is my understanding that 2016 Muse headband behaves differently. It uses bluetooth low energy and muse-io does not work with it.

Answer (score 2):

This means that your Mac has remembered you connecting to it before but it is currently not in range. Try restarting the device or bringing it closer.

The Bluetooth is working as connect appears on the other device.

Comment: Uhhh, no to the last sentence.  "Bluetooth hardware recognized" ≠ "Bluetooth hardware working properly." The presence of the "Connect" button in no way indicates BT is functional.  You must diagnose properly by connecting the BT headset to a *known working device* to verify it's working there and likewise, connect *different* known working BT devices to the Mac.